# Spring-boot LDAP - Property 'userDn' not set

Tags: spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap

I am running a Spring-boot application which authenticates users via our internal LDAP with spring-security-ldap.

By default it binds with LDAP anonymously.

`Property 'userDn' not set - anonymous context will be used for read-write operations`

But I want the first bind to be with current username.

Where should I specify the userDn attribute?

Thank you for your advice

Comment: Typically the userDn is derived from the username input. The code should resolve the username into a DN and authenticate (bind) with that DN + the password input.

Comment: And is there a way to verify the userDn has been filed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

When using spring ldap maybe you started from one many tutorials on the web but main of them uses embedded ldap server; embdedded server uses ldif file and doesn't need the manager credetials.

When connecting to an external ldap server you need to specify userDn setting it via managerDn method. Here the snippet of code

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.ldapAuthentication().contextSource().managerDn("uid=admin,ou=system")
        .managerPassword("secret")
.......
}
```

Obviously you need to provide also all the other infos like url, port, etc (and userSearchBase like mvreijn told).

Answer (score -1):

I am not the most knowledgeable person regarding Spring-boot, more so regarding LDAP.
That said, your LDAP configuration properties should be mentioned in your `application.properties` file and are named `spring.ldap.*`.
They are mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html).

When initializing your authentication provider, you can pass important properties like the Base DN (root to search from) and the filter using:

```
.userSearchBase("ou=<your users container>").userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
```

Most likely, your search filter will be `uid={0}` or `cn={0}`.

Comment: This do not answer why he gets that error.